# how to change win form controls to wpf?

Tags: wpf, winforms

here is the win form control im stuck with, columnheader, may I know what has the control name changed to?

```
private System.Windows.Controls.ColumnHeader yColumnHeader;
        private System.Windows.Controls.ColumnHeader estimatedYColumnHeader;
```

Comment: you can use ListView with GridView as the View and define columns as needed

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample for `ListView` with `GridView` as `View` to display your content.

`GridViewColumn.Header` in the example is somewhat similar to `ColumnHeader` in winforms

sample

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmployeeInfoDataSource}}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true"
                  ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"
                            Header="First Name"
                            Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
                            Width="100">
                <GridViewColumnHeader>Last Name
                    <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu  MenuItem.Click="LastNameCM_Click"
                                      Name="LastNameCM">
                            <MenuItem Header="Ascending" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Descending" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EmployeeNumber}"
                            Header="Employee No."
                            Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

sample result

[image: result]

above example is taken from [How to: Display ListView Contents by Using a GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747048(v=vs.110).aspx)